# Extreme difficulty setting up VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Oh my god, there are so many tutorials out there, and all of them involve complicated instructions that don't work. I'm really about to cry, and it's the first time I'm getting emotional over a computer thing.

I need to set up a VPN, like I could by double clicking Hotspot Shield on Ubuntu. I tried OpenVPN, part of their instructions went like this:

```
mkdir /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/
cp -r /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/2.0/* /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/
```

Here's what happened:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/2.0/2.0/*’: No such file or directory
```

Can someone please help me? I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Is this an employer's VPN or one you subscribe to personally? If it's the latter, you could try AirVPN, which I use. They have a nice application the connects and disconnects to their VPN service with the click of a mouse. Reasonable price, to. `airvpn.org`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure easy-rsa is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install easy-rsa
```

If you are using 14.04.1 the command to create the easy-rsa dir and add everything you need is:

```
sudo make-cadir /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
```

After that you can just cd to /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa and create your keys as the tutorial says.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

as a pure Debian fan, please consult: https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN
Chapter: TLS-enabled VPN
Where is stated that from Jessie and above easy-rsa is located in: /usr/share/easy-rsa/
Everything else is the same....

Best regards,
Vedro